# Can I use completion buffer instead of menu with auto complete in emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'd like to use completion as emacs' origin behavior: With `emacs -q` and

```
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
```

When hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, gives me a completion buffer showing all candidates. Can I do this using `auto complete` ? I prefer its various sources for different mode but I don't want to use its menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be too hard to write a simple "adapter", i.e. a function that you can add to `completion-at-point-functions` and which will use the auto-complete sources to provide completion data to `completion-at-point`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it won't be too hard :)